# Help in the following code

Tags: python, ftplib

```
def startConnection(self):
    from ftplib import FTP
    self.ftp = FTP(self.loginServer)
    print 'Loging In'
    print self.ftp.login(self.username, self.password)
    data = []
    self.ftp.dir(data.append)
    for line in data:
        try:
            self.date_str = ' '.join(line.split()[5:8])
            newDate = time.strptime(self.date_str,'%b %d %H:%M')
            print newDate
            col_list = line.split()
            name = col_list[0]
            tempDir = {}

            if name.startswith('d'):
                tempDir['directory'] = newDate
            else:
                tempDir['file']=newDate

            self.dirInfo[col_list[8]] = tempDir
        except:
            print "**********Exception for line **********\n" + line + "\n**********Exception End**********"
```

This function is working fine, 
newDate value is Aug 20 11:12, but year is missing,
so Bydefault year value it is taking 1900, which is not correct.
To debug it, i logged in ftp server and did dir / ls in both the cases it is showing timestamp like 'Aug 20 11:12'. But if i do ls -lTr, in that case it is showing year,

what i want is some how i can pass above command to ftp and get the result.
Is there any python ftplib module's function that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.ftp.dir('-lTr', data.append)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a command that gives a short-form date, or want to cope with different arguments being handed to `ls` you'll have to make multiple attempts to parse the date with different format strings, until you don't get a `ValueError`, post-processing the successful parse according to which format it has matched -- files more than a year old will often report a date format including a year but no time of day (here you could probably stick with a default 00:00:00 time); recent files reported in a format without a year can have the current year defaulted in; formats that contain a year would be left unchanged.